# What is the best way to include firebase_storage in a flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I need to storage a couple of files in Firebase. I am using android emulator.
The problem is: when I included the package in yaml (firebase_storage) I got a big error where say the next:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3.
  Required by:
      project :app > project :firebase_storage
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-storage/16.0.3/firebase-storage-16.0.3.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-storage/16.0.3/firebase-storage-16.0.3.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-storage/16.0.3/firebase-storage-16.0.3.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-storage/16.0.3/firebase-storage-16.0.3.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-storage/16.0.3/firebase-storage-16.0.3.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-storage/16.0.3/firebase-storage-16.0.3.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-storage/16.0.3/firebase-storage-16.0.3.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-storage/16.0.3/firebase-storage-16.0.3.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run
with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I tried setting up a firebase project in my flutter project following the steps given by official page of google firebase.
I tried too adding this code to my android/gradle:

```
subprojects{
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, I can not run my app because of that.
I would like to know what is the best effective way to storage files in firebase.

Comment: Did you download `google-services.json` ? checkout this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Comment: If you are using visual studio code, open your android application in Android Studio once, it will download necessary dependency lib files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider following this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0), or read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup), in case of if you have missed a step or not. (google-services.json or SHA keys etc.)

If you are all set, it might be related to AndroidX.

When you check the changelog.md, you see a **breaking change** on version [0.9.0](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#090).

[image]

Try avoiding AndroidX by using [previous packages](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx), or [migrate](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#how-to-migrate-a-flutter-app-to-androidx) your project to AndroidX.

Comment: Reallly hellpful!